# How should I handle file paths in junit when I run the tests in 2 different environments?

Tags: eclipse, ant, junit

I have all my junit tests running in eclipse.
Some of them have hardcoded relative paths to things like the properties file for the application.
Now I am getting them set up to run as part of our ant build process.
Unfortunately the ant build has a different base path. This causes the tests with the hard coded paths fail.

What options do I have to get the tests running in both environments?

Eclipse uses root as the base of paths. Ant uses root/src/test as the base. I have verified this by updating the hardcoded path, and running the tests.

The layout of the Hierarchy

```
/root/
+ config/
  + app.properties
    + src/
+ java/
  +production code/
+ test/
  + build.xml
  + junit tests/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

um... move your `build.xml` to the root and change its paths.  I'm not sure why you would want the ant build and eclipse to use different roots.

Comment: I chose this as the simpler solution for me to implement. I am sure there are many good points to Raedwalds answer if I was starting from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have hard-coded full paths. Instead, have paths configured separately, or relative to a few root paths (my preference), which you configure. Consider using dependecy injection to configure your unit tested code with the paths to use. Your unit tests can use fake paths, and your `main` method can configure the deployed code to use the real paths.